# I'm looking for a working copy of Kendo-UI Grid (just like in the dojo) that actually works

Tags: user-interface, grid, kendo-ui

I've run through the dojo from Kendo UI, but I can't seem to get it to work locally.  Here's my sample (as derived from the DOJO):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.data.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.grid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        var movies = [
            { Title: "Star Wars: A New Hope", Year: 1977 },
            { Title: "Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back", Year: 1980 },
            { Title: "Star Wars: Return of the Jedi", Year: 1983 }
        ];

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: movies
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="grid"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have included almost every single kendo JavaScript file. You only need to include kendo.all.min.js - it contains every other file. More information can be found in the [JavaScript Dependencies](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies) help topic.

There is another problem. Your code is executed immediately and the DIV of the grid is not yet part of the DOM. $("#grid") will return nothing.

Here is the fixed version of your code: http://jsbin.com/esalih/1/edit